# How to run a bash script from another computer?

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

I have developed a Python application which needs to call a bash script stored in another computer (Raspberry Pi).

I don't need to get any return value nor confirmation.

What are the feasible ways to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [tag:paramiko], this is third party lib for python to do ssh operation.

Comment: Or fabric: http://www.fabfile.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the shell you could do it like this:

```
ssh pi@theraspberrypi "./myscript"
```

To run a shell command from in Python:

```
import os
os.system("ssh pi@theraspberrypi ./myscript")
```

Or, as Eevee suggested below:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ssh pi@theraspberrypi ./myscript'], shell=True)
```

Of course, you will probably want to put your public key in the raspberry pi's authorized_keys file so it won't prompt for a password.

Comment: definitely prefer `subprocess`, which will save you from mucking about with shell quoting and escaping.  (though in this case, the quotes aren't necessary anyway.)